# A GAP code for maximum and minimum cardinals of some classes of subsets of a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, gap, computational-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group with a fixed subset $A$. Put
$$
S_r(A)=\{B\subseteq G : |AB|=|A||B|\; \& \;  B  \; \mbox{is inclusion-maximal with respect  to this property}\}
$$
$$
M_r(A)=\max\{|B| : B\in S_r(A) \}
$$
$$
m_r(A)=\min\{|B| : B\in S_r(A) \}
$$
($S_\ell(A)$, $M_\ell(A)$ and $m_\ell(A)$ are defined analogously).

Now, I need a **GAP code for  evaluating** $S_r(A)$, $M_r(A)$ and $m_r(A)$  ($\; S_\ell(A)$, $M_\ell(A)$ and $m_\ell(A)$).

**Note.** Always $S_r(A)\neq\emptyset$ and
$$
M_r(A)=\max\{|B| : B\subseteq G \; \& \; |AB|=|A||B|\}
$$
If $A\leq G$ then $M_r(A)=m_r(A)=M_\ell(A)=m_\ell(A)=|G:A|$.

(also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177747/factorization-of-a-finite-group-by-two-subsets)

Comment: Enumerating all eligible $B$ would be expensive. What have you tried, and where is the first difficulty?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, for your message. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with GAP. If it is difficult, evaluating $M_r(A)$ and $m_r(A)$ are enough.

Comment: Hm, but anyway to get to them one should find $S_r(A)$ first, so this doesn't simplify the task at all (inclusion-maximal is easy to check as soon as you would find all such $B$).

Comment: If you would like to learn GAP, what about trying [Software Carpentry lesson "Programming with GAP"](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/)? I am happy to help answering more narrowed down questions. I am less keen to answer questions formulated like "I need a GAP code for" since my teaching approach is [to teach how to do it rather then to provide a ready solution](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime).